Use Interpolating function from NDSolve as an initial condition for another NDSolve
The following are the 4 parts of my code. The 1st part is constant definition. The 2nd part is function definition. The 3rd part is equation solving which works as expected. The 4th part tries to use the results from the 3rd part to evolve the function logf further, which doesn't work. I'm suspecting that the error arises from setting an inappropriate initial condition.
(**** 1st ****)
ClearAll["Global`*"]
lp0 := Log[5 10^-3];
lpf := Log[4];
\[Kappa]f = 1;
Qs := 1;
\[Xi] := 2;
\[Sigma]0 := 0.1;
g := 0.01;
Nc := 3;
\[Lambda] := g^4/(4 \[Pi]) Nc;

(**** 2nd ****)
intflogB[logf_] := 
  2/(2 \[Pi])^2 NIntegrate[
    E^(3 lp) Exp[logf], {lp, lp0, lpf}, {\[Kappa], 0, \[Kappa]f}];
intfsqrlogB[logf_] := 
  2/(2 \[Pi])^2 NIntegrate[
    E^(3 lp) Exp[logf]^2, {lp, lp0, lpf}, {\[Kappa], 0, \[Kappa]f}];
intfoverplogB[logf_] := 
  2/(2 \[Pi])^2 NIntegrate[
    E^(2 lp) Exp[logf], {lp, lp0, lpf}, {\[Kappa], 0, \[Kappa]f}];
exppTsqrlogB[logf_] := 
  2/(2 \[Pi])^2 NIntegrate[(1 - \[Kappa]^2) E^(5 lp) Exp[logf], {lp, 
     lp0, lpf}, {\[Kappa], 0, \[Kappa]f}];
exppzsqrlogB[logf_] := 
  2/(2 \[Pi])^2 NIntegrate[\[Kappa]^2 E^(5 lp) Exp[logf], {lp, lp0, 
     lpf}, {\[Kappa], 0, \[Kappa]f}];  
getIalogB[logf_] := intflogB[logf] + intfsqrlogB[logf];
getIblogB[logf_] := 2 intfoverplogB[logf];
mDsqrlogB[f_] := 2 Nc g^2 getIblogB[f];
getlCblogB[f_] := Sqrt[exppTsqrlogB[f]/intflogB[f]]/mDsqrlogB[f];
Clear[makeLog\[Tau]vals];
makeLog\[Tau]vals[begin_, end_, length_] := (
  (10^# & /@ 
     Array[# &, length, {Log[begin]/Log[10], Log[end]/Log[10]}]) // N
  )
Clear[logfi, fi];
logfi[lp_, \[Kappa]_] := (Log[\[Sigma]0/g^2 ] - (
   Exp[2 lp] (1 - (1 - \[Xi]^2) \[Kappa]^2))/Qs^2)
fi[lp_, \[Kappa]_] := 
 Exp[Log[\[Sigma]0/g^2 ] - (Exp[2 lp] (1 - (1 - \[Xi]^2) \[Kappa]^2))/
   Qs^2]

(**** 3rd ****)
IaNow = getIalogB[logfi[lp, \[Kappa]]];
LNow = getlCblogB[logfi[lp, \[Kappa]]];
i = 1;
\[Tau]i = 70;
\[Tau]f = 71;
\[Tau]ini = \[Tau]i;
myeqn = {
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(logf\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[lp, \[Kappa], \[Tau]] + (
     1/\[Tau])\[Kappa] ((-1 + \[Kappa]^2) 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(logf\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[lp, \[Kappa], \[Tau]] - \[Kappa] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(logf\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[
          lp, \[Kappa], \[Tau]]) == \[Lambda] Ia lCb E^(-2 lp) (-2 \
\[Kappa] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(logf\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[
         lp, \[Kappa], \[Tau]] - (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(logf\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[lp, \[Kappa], \[Tau]] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(logf\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[lp, \[Kappa], \[Tau]]^2) +
       
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(logf\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[lp, \[Kappa], \[Tau]] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(logf\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[lp, \[Kappa], \[Tau]] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(logf\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[lp, \[Kappa], \[Tau]]^2),
   logf[lp, \[Kappa], \[Tau]ini] == inicond};
eqnow = myeqn //. {Ia -> IaNow, lCb -> LNow, \[Tau]ini -> \[Tau]i, 
    inicond -> logfi[lp, \[Kappa]]};

sol = NDSolve[eqnow, 
  logf, {lp, lp0, lpf}, {\[Kappa], 
   0, \[Kappa]f}, {\[Tau], \[Tau]i, \[Tau]f},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 10^-3}}}]

newlogfi[lp_, \[Kappa]_] := logf[lp, \[Kappa], \[Tau]f] //. sol[[1]];
newlogfi // StandardForm;

(**** 4th ****)
IaNow = getIalogB[newlogfi[lp, \[Kappa]]]
LNow = getlCblogB[newlogfi[lp, \[Kappa]]]
\[Tau]i = 71;
\[Tau]f = 72;
eqnow = myeqn //. {Ia -> IaNow, lCb -> LNow, \[Tau]ini -> \[Tau]i, 
    inicond -> newlogfi[lp, \[Kappa]]};
sol = NDSolve[eqnow, 
  logf, {lp, lp0, lpf}, {\[Kappa], 
   0, \[Kappa]f}, {\[Tau], \[Tau]i, \[Tau]f},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 10^-3}}}]

I'm trying to use the resulting interpolating function newlogfi from the 3rd part as an initial condition for the 4th part. But Mathematica gives me:
NDSolve`FEM`ElementMesh: The mesh elements are not valid. A set of valid mesh element \
incidents needs to be positive integers and be able to form a \
complete sequence starting from 1 to the largest incident present. \
There are missing incidents; a complete sequence cannot be formed.

Compile:
"InterpolatingFunction[{{-5.29832,1.38629},{0.,1.},{70.,71.}},{5,\
12417,1,{25,20841,0},{4,3,3},0,0,0,0,Indeterminate&,<<3>>},{NDSolve`\
FEM`ElementMesh[{{-5.29832,0.},{-5.29832,0.03125},{-5.29832,0.0625},<<\
5>>,{-5.29832,0.25},{-5.29832,0.28125},<<20831>>},<<3>>],{70.,<<9>>,<<\
15>>}},{<<1>>},{Automatic,Automatic}][<<1>>] cannot be compiled and \
will be evaluated externally. The result is assumed to be of type \
Real."

The initial condition logfi[lp,k] of the first NDSolve  and the second newlogfi[lp,k] seem to have the same structure as they both give numerical values when evaluate the following
logfi[1,0]
newlogfi[1,0]

How to resolve this problem?

Note that newlogfi[lp, [Kappa]] requests a time at 72 while the time range is from 70 to 71. That looks suspicious. Even if I fix that by commenting out the ([Tau]i=71;
[Tau]f=72;) there are still places where you evaluate the interpolating function outside of it's domain. Try to re-write your code in terms of functions that get the values and produce the equations you want in stead of the rule based approach.
